# Android:Picking random string from an array and using it in setImageResource command

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi:I am new in java and i need to set a random image into an imageview by pressing a button: i have tried in a lot of different ways (the one in the example does not work) and i don't really know what to do
JAVA CODE:

```
package comad.exampleaaaa.vittoriodaadntico.dadi;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Random;

public class DADI extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView dado;
public Button azione;
public String[] immagini=    {"dice2","dice3","dice4","dice5","dice6","dice7"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dadi);
    dado=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.dice);
    azione=(Button)findViewById(R.id.roll);

        azione.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int random; // or create a static random field...
                random = new Random().nextInt(new Random(immagini.length));

                dado.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(immagini[random]));

        }});
}


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dadi, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

XML CODE:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".DADI"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

if you need more explanation please comment and thanks

Comment: can you post some questions here, thanks

Comment: ok i am going to text it

Comment: Random cannot be converted in int

Comment: Use `dado.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + immagini[random], null, getPackageName()))`

Comment: but  `random` is already `int` then no need to convert it to `int`

Comment: i don't know what that is about the problem is in this line   random = new Random(immagini.length).nextInt(new Random(immagini.length));

Comment: Use `Random r = new Random();random=r.nextInt(immagini.length)`

Comment: ok that worked but i am getting another error to this line dado.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + immagini[random], null, Context.getPackageName())); that says Error:(34, 117) error: non-static method getPackageName() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Ok `dado.setImageResource(DADI.this.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + immagini[random], null, DADI.this.getPackageName()));`

Comment: thanks it works . sorry for being annoying

Comment: just last request : are out there some tutorials that can help me on this language because  i have used only c based language and java is more complicated than c. thanks